# Agrupar somatório de coluna por trimestre

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Gostaria de agrupar o somatório de uma coluna por trimestre, isto é, de três em três meses.

Tenho a seguinte `query` que agrupa de mês a mês:

```
select month(data) as mes, year(data) as ano, ifnull(sum(det.quantidade),0) as total
    from documento as doc
    inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
    inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
    inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
    where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3 
    group by mes, ano 
    order by mes, ano desc
```

Como poderei fazer para agrupar o somatório de uma coluna nos intervalos de [Janeiro,Março],[Abril,Junho],[Julho,Setembro],[Outubro,Dezembro]?

Convém também que sejam meses referentes a um só ano.

Answer (score 1):

```
select CASE WHEN MONTH(data) in (1,2,3) THEN 'Primeiro'
            WHEN MONTH(data) in (4,5,6) THEN 'Segundo'
            WHEN MONTH(data) in (7,8,9) THEN 'Terceiro'
            WHEN MONTH(data) in (10,11,12) THEN 'Quarto'
       END AS trimestre, 
       YEAR(data) as ano, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(data) in (1,2,3) THEN det.quantidade 
                WHEN MONTH(data) in (4,5,6) THEN det.quantidade 
                WHEN MONTH(data) in (7,8,9) THEN det.quantidade 
                WHEN MONTH(data) in (10,11,12) THEN det.quantidade 
           END) as total
from documento as doc
inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3 
group by ano, CASE WHEN MONTH(data) in (1,2,3) THEN 1
                   WHEN MONTH(data) in (4,5,6) THEN 2
                   WHEN MONTH(data) in (7,8,9) THEN 3
                   WHEN MONTH(data) in (10,11,12) THEN 4
              END
order by data desc
```

Comment: Não teria como agrupar por `MONTH(data-1)/4`?

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe abaixo funciona no SQL Server, você poderia adaptá-la facilmente para o MYSQL, o importante aqui é o conceito:

```
select 

sum(case when month(data) in (1,2,3) then ifnull(det.quantidade,0) else 0 end) Tri1,
sum(case when month(data) in (4,5,6) then ifnull(det.quantidade,0) else 0 end) Tri2,
sum(case when month(data) in (7,8,9) then ifnull(det.quantidade,0) else 0 end) Tri3,
sum(case when month(data) in (10,11,12) then ifnull(det.quantidade,0) else 0 end) Tri4,
year(data) as ano

from documento as doc
inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3 
group by ano 
order by ano desc
```

Explicação:

```
sum(case when month(data) in (1,2,3) then ifnull(det.quantidade,0) else 0 end) Tri1
```

O código acima somará o valor de det.quantidade quando o mês for 1,2 ou 3, caso contrário somará 0.

Isso é feito para cada Trimestre. Assim, este SQL terá como retorno 5 colunas, sendo 1 para cada Trimestre e outra para o Ano.

Comment: Eu sou mesmo noob em mysql, mas está a dar erro. Se não colocar o "end" no 'sum' do trimestre 4, diz 'You have an error in sql syntax ..." , se colocar o end diz, 'Invalid use of group function'.

Comment: O end foi erro meu, esqueci de colocar. Acabei de editar. Sobre o erro de agrupamento, preciso investigar. Se vc trocar group by ano, por group by year(data), funciona? (troque o order by também).

Comment: Penso que continua com um end a mais no trimestre 4, de qualquer das formas testei o que me disse e dá o mesmo erro :s

Comment: O erro não é mais de sintaxe, ou seja, a engine do MySQL está parseando o SQL sem nenhum problema. O erro é dado por outro motivo. Não trabalho com MySQL, assim, preciso investigar o que pode ser. De qualquer maneira, é bem estranho isso não funcionar.

Comment: Veja também http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter